# Calculate time difference between action 'X' and next action 'non X'

Tags: sql

I would like to calculate the time difference between each action X and next(determine by time)non X action.
I have attached the sample data and desired results.
can anyone help??

[image]

Comment: I don't see the attachment.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong, it should be 1111-4 min, and 2222- 6 min.

Comment: oh my mistake, yes it should be 1111 4 minutes and 2222 6 minutes

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: i am using postgresql